# Почему в глобальной области не работает?

Tags: javascript

Друзья, помогите! Вот код для аналоговых часов. Я пытаюсь перенести `const now = new Date();` в глобальную область видимости, так как она нужна для другой функции. Но код перестаёт работать если вынести этот код в глобальную переменную из функции.

```js
const secondsH = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
const minuH = document.querySelector('.min-hand');
const hourH = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secIndeg = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  console.log(secIndeg);
  if (secIndeg === 90) {
    setMin();
    setInterval(setMin, 60000);
    console.log('go');
  }
  secondsH.style.transform = `rotate(${secIndeg}deg)`;

}

function setMin() {
  const now = new Date();
  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  console.log(minutes);
  if (minutes === 0) {
    setHour();
    setInterval(setHour, 1000 * 3600);
  }
  const minIndeg = ((minutes / 60) * 360) + 90;
  minuH.style.transform = `rotate(${minIndeg}deg)`;
}

function setHour() {
  const now = new Date();
  const hours = now.getHours();
  console.log(hours)
  const hourIndeg = ((hours / 12) * 360) + 90;
  hourH.style.transform = `rotate(${hourIndeg}deg)`;

}

setHour();
setMin();

setInterval(setDate, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="hour-hand"></div>
<div class="min-hand"></div>
<div class="second-hand"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var now;
function setDate() {
  now = new Date();
  ...
```